# mapR Kafka cannot start second time round

Tags: apache-kafka, mapr

To date I have either used an existing professional installation for Hadoop with components running, or, installed Kafka and used the also-supplied Zookeeper in a native VM.

I am trying to get the mapR Community Edition Sandbox to run now.

- There is a KAFKA library on mapR, but here is no kafka shown when using jps. Seems odd? I managed to get KAFKA to start once.
- There is a Zookeeper service on mapR but it uses port 5181, not 2181.
- Kafka uses port 9092.
- The log.dirs for kafka was set to /tmp/kafka-logs, I changed that to /opt/kafka-logs
- The dataDir was also set to /tmp/zookeeper, I changed that to /opt/zookeeper
- I also changed the Zookeeper port to 5181 as that is what mapR uses.

It ran once, and then I re-started and I still get this type of error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/kafka-logs/.lock (Permission denied)
```

I have done chmod 777 where required I think, but I changed the paths to /opt/... from /tmp.  So why is it picking /tmp up again?

I have the impression that it keeps on point to /tmp regardless of the updates to the configurations.

I also see a warning - although I do not think this is an issue:

```
[2019-01-14 13:26:46,355] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /tmp/kafka-logs/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
```

May be because of the mapR Streams I cannot influence it so as to run natively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I could delete the question as I solved it, but for those on mapR I deduced:

- You need to update the port 2181 to 5181 on server.properties immediately. In this case we integrate with an existing zookeeper instance.
- Likewise, update the log.dirs for Kafka from /tmp/kafka-logs asap to /opt/kafka-logs.
- Likewise, update the dataDir from /tmp/zookeeper asap to /opt/zookeeper.

Trying to fix latterly otherwise leads to all sorts of issues. I ended up just re-installing and doing it right from scratch.

mapR has a faster version called mapR Streams which implements Kafka. I was not wanting to use that for what I was wanting to do, but mapR Sandbox has a lot of up-to-date items straight out of the box -certainly compared to Cloudera.

Comment: Absolutely don't use `/tmp` for critical data :) Not sure on the port number

Comment: They all come configured with that out of the box I have noted. @cricket_007

Comment: Yes, Kafka and Zookeeper default to `/tmp`. That isn't specific to MapR, or any other vendor, AFAIK